# Flex: XML data from httpservice in repeater

Tags: xml, apache-flex, httpservice

I'm trying to populate a label with a result from an httpservice. This result comes from a phpscript which generates xml. When I run it I just get a blank page. My application code is as follows:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           initialize="doSend()">
<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.collections.ArrayList;
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent; 

        [Bindable]
        private var myData:XML;
        public function doSend():void 
        {
            getWatchlist.send();
        }

        protected function getXML(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var myData:XML = XML(event.result);
            rptWatchlist.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(myData.movies);
        }

    ]]>

</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:HTTPService url="http://****/phpscripts/selectWatchlist.php"
                    id="getWatchlist" 
                    showBusyCursor="true" 
                    method="POST"
                    result="getXML(event)"
                    resultFormat="e4x">
        <!--todo: userid ophalen -->
        <!--<mx:request xmlns="">
            <userid>
                1
            </userid>
        </mx:request>-->
    </mx:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Repeater id="rptWatchlist">
        <s:Label text="{rptWatchlist.currentItem.movie}" />
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:HBox>
```

'

The result from my phpscript is an xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <movies>
  <movie>
       <watched>N</watched>
       <poster_url>http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/2lECpi35Hnbpa4y46JX0aY3AWTy.jpg</poster_url>
       <movie_title>Fight Club</movie_title>
  </movie>
  </movies>
```

Comment: Repeaters are tricky; and I do not believe changing the dataProvider on a repeater will cause it to re-loop over the elements; which is why you're seeing nothing.  I strongly suggest using a List instead.  I've found repeaters to be nothing but problems.

Comment: change this new XMLListCollection(myData.movies); to new XMLListCollection(myData.movie); what you are after is a list of movies... myData.movie returns an XMLList of all of the movie nodes.  myData.movies is the root and will return nothing.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I switched over to a TileList and changed declaration of my XMLListCollection as per your suggestion. I can now access childnodes of my xml (through an itemrenderer in my tilelist) with {data.movie_title}.

Answer (score -1):

visi http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex2_04.html for similar kind of example

Comment: -1 because generally questions that contain no data but a link are not considered acceptable.  If you were to edit your answer to quote the relevant passages from the link, that would be considered better.